# unable to set .env varible into my view/js files using laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I am unable to load `.env` variables into my views I have tried different ways but I am unable to solve my problem.

My file name is

> custom-script.js

My Code:

```
function sendBusinessDetails(saveform) {

                    $.ajax({//Process the form using $.ajax()
                        type: 'post', //Method type
                        url: window.APP_URL+'/Process', // here is the problem
                        data: saveform, //Forms name
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data && data.status === 1) {
                                alert("success");
                                window.location.href = "Page-list";

                            } else {
                                $("#unsuccesserror").html(data.message).show(500);
                            }


                            // window.location.href = "New-Sale-Page";

                        }
                    });
                }
```

My `APP_URL = http://localhost:8000`
and I am replacing with

```
url: window.APP_URL+'/Process', // here is the problem
```

I have also tried another way:

```
               <?php echo env('APP_URL');?>
```

but I am unable to solve this:
Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Env variables are not supposed to be consumed directly in your code apart from configs. Rather, config variables should be consumed from their respective config. Assuming the

> 'url' => env('APP_URL')

exits in config/app.php (if not add it) you can get its value using

```
{{Config::get('app.url')}}
```

in your blade.

Comment: in lumen there is not config folder what we will do then?

Comment: Above is a question and answer specific to Laravel.
One problem at a time :)

Comment: sorry i did not mention but i have two server one for api and other for app and in app i am using lumen so this problelm is in lumen

Comment: anyway to do in lumen/?

Comment: Sorry. Not aware about that.